# How to check if argv[count] is an integer

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I'm trying to create a command line application in C++ and I want to make sure that the input is an integer after a certain command argument.

For this example, I want to check if the next argument is an integer after the "-p" command argument. Here's the snippet of my code right now.

```
while (count < argc){
    if (strcmp("-p", argv[count]) == 0){
        has_p = true; //Boolean
        pid = atoi(argv[count + 1]);
        if (pid == 0 && argv[count + 1] != "0" ){
            err = 1;
            cout << "pid argument is not a valid input" << endl;
            pid = -1;
        }
        count++;
    }
...
}
```

Now this code correctly catches the error in this inputs:

- -p 1777
- -p sss
- -p sss17
- -p [space] -U

but fails at this input format

- -p 17sss

I tried to remedy this by trying to compare it using sprintf. Unfortunately supplying sprintf with the char array pointer only outputs 1 character in buffer2.

```
while (count < argc){
    if (strcmp("-p", argv[count]) == 0){
        has_p = true; //Boolean
        pid = atoi(argv[count + 1]);
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", pid);
        sprintf(buffer2, "%d", *argv[count + 1]);
        if (pid == 0 && argv[count + 1] != "0" || (buffer != buffer2) ){
            err = 1;
            cout << "pid argument is not a valid input" << endl;
            pid = -1;
        }
        count++;
    }
...
}
```

Is there a way to make sprintf read the whole char array? If not, is there a better solution for this apart from looping through the pointer until I hit "\0"

Comment: Choose a language. You say C++, but you're using C idioms, and the question is tagged with both.

Comment: [`isdigit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/)

Comment: Use `strcmp` for comparing two strings,  not `!=`. You can use `if( isdigit(argv[count]) )` to check if the argument is a digit.

Comment: oh my bad. I'm programming in visual studio 2013 so I tagged it as c++. But I want it to compile in c also.

Comment: UPDATE "I want it to compile in c also" - then remove the C++ tag. // For C++, boost's `lexical_cast<int>(argv[count + 1])` is a good option - it will throw if an `int` can't be parsed from the text, or if there's garbage text afterwards....

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel by parsing your own arguments? What is wrong with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt ?

Comment: isdigit works on per character basis right so It can't check values more than 9

Comment: edit: I just now realized that the != comparison was in the if statement. I placed that condition since atoi returns 0 if the first character was not a digit

Comment: Im not realy sure you want to include boost, but it has easy [boost::program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/program_options.html) lib.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`atoi()` cannot do what you want. You need to use [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) to achieve this. It has much improved error checking capacity.

**Signature:**

```
long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

This function returns the converted integral number as a long int value, else zero value is returned. 
After the conversion, you can check the contents of `endptr`  and decide upon that.

Comment: On a side note: `endptr` will be set to point to the first character after the number, so if the number is a valid integer, it should point to a null-terminator which ends the string. In other words, to check whether the conversion was successful, do `if (*endptr == 0)`

Comment: you can use functions return value to decide.

Comment: @ANjaNA - No, you can't use the return value to determine if the conversion failed because the return value when the conversion fails is also a possible result from a successful conversion.  You **must** use the value of `endptr`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle This is why `atoi` is so retarded. Seriously, I'd like to meet whoever introduced `atoi`, `atof`, and `gets` into the standard and ask them what they were thinking at the time.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a convenient one-liner...

```
sscanf(argv[count + 1], "%d%*c", &n) == 1
```

...that will evaluate true if it was possible to read into the `int n` and there was no trailing character afterwards.  The '*' in `%*c` suppresses assignment, so there's no need to pass a pointer to a dummy `char` variable.  See [scanf docs here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: I tried this and it's the same as above problem. Works with those following inputs but fails on catching the error for "-p 17ss" input

Comment: @MDuh: how does it "fail"? - you can see [here](http://ideone.com/fiMTbo) how `sscanf` with that text returns `0`... as per the `== 1` test above, that does mean it caught the error.  It's when it returns exactly 1 that the input is valid and `n` will be set to the numeric value thereof.

Comment: To be more explicit, for your particular use case you want `if (sscanf(argv[count + 1], "%d%*c", &pid) != 1) { err = 1; cout << "pid argument is not a valid input" << endl; pid = -1; }` etc...

Comment: ohh, yep. Missed that part, forgot to replace my if condition >.>. Yep actually works also now.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the c++11 alternatives, that are implemented in terms of strtol (see [stol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)).

Comment: This doesn't deserve downvotes as it was posted while the question was also tagged C++....

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can simply go through the char* and check if there are digits only.

```
char c = '0';
int i = 0;
int err = 0
while ( c != '\0'){
    if (arg[i] < 47 || arg[i] > 57){
        err = 1;
        break;
    }
```